# Cancellation property of vector bundles on non-proper varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Krull-Schmidt theorem for proper varieties over a field implies that given an isomorphism of vector bundles between $E\oplus F$ and $G\oplus F$ we can deduce that $E$ and $G$ are isomorphic. My question is, does this cancellation property hold if I replace the proper variety $X$ with $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$?

What if I know for the two vector bundles $E$ and $G$ on $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$ ($X$ is smooth proper or projective) there is a reflexive sheaf $F$ such that $E\oplus F\cong G\oplus F$. Then can we deduce that there is a vector bundle $F'$ such that $E\oplus F'\cong G\oplus F'$. (The reflexive sheaf is
a vector bundle outside a closed subvariety of the form $Z\times \mathbb{A}^1$ where $Z$ is a closed subvariety of $X$ of codimension $2$)